# How do I retrieve the type of a property from a Lambda and infer it on a list?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, lambda, sieve.net

### Background

I'm trying to start [a little Github open-source project.](https://github.com/SeanKilleen/Sieve.NET). It helps to create filters that can be returned as `Expression<Func<ABusinessObject, bool>>` or compiled into `Func<ABusinessObject, bool>`.

Currently, I have to define my object in the following way, including `, int>` to specify the property type:

```
new EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject, int>()
    .ForProperty(x=>x.AnInt)
    .ForValues("1, 2, 3");
```

It contains a property called `AcceptableValues`, which is the same type as the property (`TPropertyType` elsewhere in my code.). I use this to let users see which values are currently acceptable to the Sieve.

### Goal

I'd like to be able to remove the `, int>` portion and write this code in the following manner:

```
new EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject>()
    .ForProperty(x=>x.AnInt)
    .ForValues("1, 2, 3");
```

And have the `AcceptableValues` list have a type of`int` inferred.

### The Current State

The code that lets me do this is the following, based almost entirely on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression).

```
/// <param name="propertyLambda">A lambda that indicates the property that we'd like to filter on.</param>
/// <remarks>
/// This is almost entirely possible due to the excellent answer on:
/// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression
/// </remarks>
public EqualitySieve<TTypeOfObjectToFilter, TPropertyType> ForProperty(Expression<Func<TTypeOfObjectToFilter, TPropertyType>> propertyLambda)
{
    Type typePropertyShouldBeFrom = typeof(TTypeOfObjectToFilter);
    var member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.",propertyLambda));

    var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propInfo == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.",propertyLambda));

    Debug.Assert(propInfo.ReflectedType != null, "propInfo.ReflectedType != null");
    if (typePropertyShouldBeFrom != propInfo.ReflectedType &&
    !typePropertyShouldBeFrom.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expresion '{0}' refers to a property that is not from type {1}.",propertyLambda,
                typePropertyShouldBeFrom));

    PropertyToFilter = propInfo;

    return this;
}
```

### Question

Is there an elegant way to make the transition here? I'm not worried about the API since the project is in pre-alpha, but it would be great if I could keep the `AcceptableValues` list and ensure that it would remain the same type as the property.

**Note**: Since technically any Sieve needs to operate on a property, I'd also be fine with removing `ForProperty` and instead putting the lambda expression in the constructor if that would help move towards a more elegant solution.

PS. While I'm looking to learn, also feel free to submit as a pull request (this is [issue #27](https://github.com/SeanKilleen/Sieve.NET/issues/27)) and I'd be happy to give you credit as a project contributor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I can help point in the right direction, even if I can't offer anything conclusive.

The salient point is that you'll need to make use of generic methods, which can infer type (generic classes cannot).  That is, If you have a method like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Something<T>(T value) { }
}
```

Then you can write simply `new Foo().Something("a string")`, and the compiler will infer that `T` is `string`.  But if the generic is at the class level:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public void Something(T value) { }
}
```

Then you would always have to specify `T` explicitly as in `new Foo<string>().Something("a string")`.

Applying the above, I would say that what you need is some concept of a "builder" class that constructs intermediate values.  Given the syntax you want, I would suggest something like below:

```
// sieve will be of type "EqualitySieve<ABusinessObject, int>"

var sieve = new EqualitySieveBuilder<ABusinessObject>()
    .ForProperty(x=>x.AnInt)
    .ForValues("1, 2, 3");
```

The `EqualitySieveBuilder<T>` class would be a sort of intermediate, with functions that return the actual `EqualitySieve<T, TProperty>` instances:

```
public class EqualitySieveBuilder<T>
{
    public EqualitySieve<T, TProperty> ForProperty<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return new EqualitySieve<T, TProperty>()
            .ForProperty(propertyExpression);
    }
}
```

You can then get fancier with this approach, adding multiple interfaces that encapsulate various intermediate stages of constructing the final instance.

Comment: Thank you! I think this approach is exactly what I'm looking for; was just having trouble wrapping my head around it. I'll try it out and then mark this as correct. I appreciate the thorough explanation too.

Comment: It seems that in this case the compiler is still unable to infer `TProperty` from the `propertyExpression`. I wonder if it can only infer if it's strictly a `T value` situation?

Comment: Gist posted here with screenshots in case I've missed something: https://gist.github.com/SeanKilleen/2604492da5143e747df1

Comment: @SeanKilleen gaahh, sorry, there were many many typos in my post.  My edit above should work, I verified in VS.

Comment: Ahh, I see the difference in syntax now. Thank you so much for taking the time to head back and correct! I learned a lot from this.

Comment: PS I've added thanks to [the project's acknowledgements page](https://github.com/SeanKilleen/Sieve.NET/wiki/Acknowledgements). Let me know if you want to swap in your real name or a different URL.